# If statement not working properly in python

Tags: python, for-loop

First, I opened the file and wrote some numbers to it.

```
writeFile = open("charge_accounts.txt", "w")
writeFile.write("5658845\n")
writeFile.write("4520125\n")
writeFile.write("7895122\n")
writeFile.write("8777541\n")
writeFile.write("8451277\n")
writeFile.write("1302850\n")
writeFile.write("8080152\n")
writeFile.write("4562555\n")
writeFile.write("5552012\n")
writeFile.write("5050552\n")
writeFile.write("7825877\n")
writeFile.write("1250255\n")
writeFile.write("1005231\n")
writeFile.write("6545231\n")
writeFile.write("3852085\n")
writeFile.write("7576651\n")
writeFile.write("7881200\n")
writeFile.write("4581002\n")

writeFile.close()
writeFile = open ("charge_accounts.txt", "r")
print writeFile.read()
```

Now, I try to search a number in the file. If number is found print Valid input. But my code doesnot print Valid input, even if i enter correct input.

```
digit = raw_input('Input seven-digit account number: ')
digit2 = len(str(digit))
digit = str(digit)
if digit2 == 7:
    text = open('charge_accounts.txt', "r")
    for line in text:
        digit3 = line
        print 'here', line, "num", digit, "\n"
        if line in digit:
        print "\n Valid input"
```

Comment: It's not clear what your're asking

Comment: Did you mean `if digit in line`?

Comment: Please rethink the names of your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the `line` strings still has the `\n` at it's end, so even though the lines and numbers seem to be the same, `if line in digit:` can not work. Instead, reverse it:

```
if digit in line:
```

Also, `digit` is already a string after `raw_input`, so no need to convert it. And you should use `with` to open *and close* the file.

```
digit = raw_input('Input seven-digit account number: ')
if len(digit) == 7:
    with open('charge_accounts.txt') as text:
        for line in text:
            print 'here', repr(line), "num", digit, "\n"
            if digit in line:
                print "\n Valid input"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work :-

```
    digit = raw_input('Input seven-digit account number: ')
    digit2 = len(str(digit))
    digit = str(digit)
    if digit2 == 7:
        print 'hello'
        text = open('charge_accounts.txt', "r")
        for line in text:
            digit3 = line
            print 'here', line, "num", digit, "\n"
            if int(line) == int(digit):
                print "\n Valid input"
```